# Asus F5R Webcam shows black screen in Skype and Cheese, but works fine with VLC and Camorama

Tags: 11.10

I install new Ubuntu 11.10 32bits version. Install Syntek webcam driver. Install Skype. Try Skype preferences Video Test and Screen was black. Next I read many forums and try LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype. Nothing changed.Where is the problem?

Comment: Have you managed to solve this problem or are you still looking for help? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned. Unaccepted answer or unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Flagged for closure. Thanks!